# passing an object in (multidimensional) $.each to function outside of closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, multidimensional-array, each

I want to pass a product object from an $.each (inside a function) loop to a function outside the closure.

When I console.log the product (object) it gives me:

"Uncaught ReferenceError: product is not defined"

Here's my code, please tell me what I am missing:

```
function openMenu(url){

    // get feed from API
    $.getJSON(url, function(storedata) {
      $('#live-menu').addClass('active');
      $('.live-menu-content').addClass('active');

      // each the feed data
      $.each(storedata, function(categoryName, productObject){
        // category title and open table
        $('.live-menu-content').append('<h1 class="menu-category-title">'+categoryName+'</h1>');
        $('.live-menu-content').append('<table class="table table-'+categoryName+'"><tbody>');

        //go through products
        $.each( productObject, function( productId, product ) { j++;
          $('.table-'+categoryName+'').append('<tr><td>'+product.name+'<br/><small>'+product.description+'</small></td><td>€'+product.price+'</td><td><a onclick="addToCart(product);" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">Add</a></td></tr>');
        });

        // close table
        $('.live-menu-content').append('</tbody></table>');
      });

    })
    // on fail
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "Error!" );
    });
    return false;
  }

  function addToCart(product){
    console.log(product);
    return false;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you realize this, but your `product` is only defined within your `each` function scope. And that product is used to render a DOM element. And instead of rendering your **actual product**, it is rendering the literal string "product", which doesn't exist outside the scope of your loop. When the DOM element is clicked, the click event is in an entirely separate scope. Can you pass the id of product to the function instead? And then lookup the product within your handler function? You would also need to create a global `store` object to reference it later:

```
var store;
function openMenu(url){

    // get feed from API
    $.getJSON(url, function(storedata) {
      store = storedata; //assign to global object
      $('#live-menu').addClass('active');
      $('.live-menu-content').addClass('active');

      // each the feed data
      $.each(storedata, function(categoryName, productObject){
        // category title and open table
        $('.live-menu-content').append('<h1 class="menu-category-title">'+categoryName+'</h1>');
        $('.live-menu-content').append('<table class="table table-'+categoryName+'"><tbody>');

        //go through products
        $.each( productObject, function( productId, product ) { j++;
          $('.table-'+categoryName+'').append('<tr><td>'+product.name+'<br/><small>'+product.description+'</small></td><td>€'+product.price+'</td><td><a onclick="addToCart("' + productId + '");" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" href="#">Add</a></td></tr>');
        });

        // close table
        $('.live-menu-content').append('</tbody></table>');
      });

    })
    // on fail
    .fail(function() {
      alert( "Error!" );
    });
    return false;
  }

  function addToCart(productId){
    var product = store.filter(function(category, catIndex){
        return category.filter(function(product, prodIndex){
            return (prodIndex == productId);
        });
    });
    console.log(product);
    return false;
  };
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. The problem with passing just the productId is that the data needs to be stored in the cart as-is at the moment upon entering the menu due to varying names, descriptions and pricing.

If I could pass those through to the function aswell it would be settled, the pricing doesn't seem to be a problem, but the name gives me "is not defined" as well. any idea?

Comment: So are you performing another ajax call to get updated data? Where does that happen?

Comment: And if you are, can't you just update the global `store` object with the updated data? The product id's don't change, do they?

Comment: The 'cart' will be posted to the API upon 'checkout' of the cart, which will happen later on. The data should not be updated and will still have to be presented as-is in the 'order' no matter what the pricing or name changes to, only the ID will be the reference to the product.

I tried doing:
addToCart(' + productId + ', '+product.name+');

but it will just give me a:
"testproduct is not defined"
error when I console.log it

Comment: Ah how foolish of me, I had to change: addToCart(' + productId + ', '+product.name+');  to addToCart(' + productId + ',  \'' + product.name + '\'); ofcourse... :)

Comment: Oh yes, that is definitely an option as well. Best of luck.